# React Router with Wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess, routing

I am using React Router (React app in a home page) with WordPress.
The problem is when a user first loads a page with client URL route, for example `site . com/recommendations`, they see a 404 error.

I can't redirect a user, because in this case the URL will be changed, too.
I know, I can do it if I change `.htaccess`, but I want to be dynamic.

What I did for now:

```
function i_redirect() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^recommendations', "index.php", 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'i_redirect');
```

But still shows 404, if I access `/recommendations` .